# Converting a tuple of options to an option of tuple with Scalaz or Shapeless

Tags: scala, scalaz, shapeless

Having

```
(Some(1), Some(2))
```

I expect to get

```
Some((1, 2))
```

and having

```
(Some(1), None)
```

I expect to get

```
None
```

Comment: Why not just `val (aOpt, bOpt) = optPair; aOpt.flatMap(a => bOpt.map(b => (a, b)))`?

Comment: @ErikAllik The question was about Scalaz specifically.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the fact that Scalaz 7 provides a `Bitraverse` instance for tuples and then sequence as usual (but with `bisequence` instead of `sequence`):

```
scala> import scalaz._, std.option._, std.tuple._, syntax.bitraverse._
import scalaz._
import std.option._
import std.tuple._
import syntax.bitraverse._

scala> val p: (Option[Int], Option[String]) = (Some(1), Some("a"))
p: (Option[Int], Option[String]) = (Some(1),Some(a))

scala> p.bisequence[Option, Int, String]
res0: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((1,a))
```

Unfortunately Scalaz 7 currently needs the type annotation here.

---

In a comment Yo Eight states that the type annotation will remain mandatory here. I'm not sure what his or her reasoning is, but it's in fact perfectly easy to write your own wrapper that will provide any appropriately typed tuple with a `bisequence` method and won't require a type annotation:

```
import scalaz._, std.option._, std.tuple._    

class BisequenceWrapper[F[_, _]: Bitraverse, G[_]: Applicative, A, B](
  v: F[G[A], G[B]]
) {
  def bisequence = implicitly[Bitraverse[F]].bisequence(v)
}

implicit def bisequenceWrap[F[_, _]: Bitraverse, G[_]: Applicative, A, B](
  v: F[G[A], G[B]]
) = new BisequenceWrapper(v)
```

Now `(some(1), some("a")).bisequence` will compile just fine.

I can't think of a good reason Scalaz wouldn't include something like this. Whether or not you want to add it in the meantime is a matter of taste, but there's definitely no theoretical obstacle to letting the compiler do the typing here.

Comment: Unfortunately, type annotations will remain mandatory in this situation

Comment: @YoEight: Why do you say that? See my edit for a working example.

Comment: @Travis Brown. You've just deferred the problem. Your wrapper holds the type information for you. The very same information you would annotate at call site. I did the same trick when I pushed MonadWriter to Scalaz.

Comment: @YoEight: I don't understand. It definitely works, in the sense that the implicit kicks in, the wrapper gets built, and the method gets called, all without the type annotation. All the wrapper does is pull together the evidence that we've got the right `Bitraverse` and `Applicative` instances.

Comment: @Travis Brown. I don't say it doest work; like I said, I used the same trick with MonadWriter. As you know after implicit resolution, your code is like: bisequenceWrap[Tuple2, Option, Int, String]((some(1), some("a"))).bisequence. My point is: It is not because you don't see it, it doesn't exist. Besides, your wrapper will not work in this case: val v: (String \/ Int, String \/ String) = (\/-(1), \/-("a")); v.bisequence

Answer (score 34):

I realize you're asking about Scalaz, but it's worth pointing out that the standard method is not unbearably wordy:

```
val x = (Some(1), Some(2))

for (a <- x._1; b <-x._2) yield (a,b)
```

In the general case (e.g. arbitrary-arity tuples), [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) is best at this sort of thing.

Comment: Sure. I kinda feel this would be the only solution, since I can't imagine how they could implement that in Scalaz, since I see no way of specifying a unified type for tuple's items, which seems to be necessary for that problem. Just asked out of curiosity

Comment: @NikitaVolkov - I am almost positive you could get Shapeless to do this, but I haven't actually had occasion to use it so I can't come up with an example.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: You're right in that you can't provide a general `Traverse` instance for tuples, but `Bitraverse` lets you get both types in there.

Answer (score 7):

I think that [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) version will not be redundant here.

```scala
@ import cats.implicits._
import cats.implicits._

@ (4.some, 2.some).bisequence
res1: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((4, 2))

@ (4.some, none).bisequence
res2: Option[Tuple2[Int, Nothing]] = None
```

Answer (score 6):

- Starting `Scala 2.13`, this exact behavior is provided in the standard library by [`Option#zip`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/Option.html#zip[A1%3E:A,B](that:Option[B]):Option[(A1,B)]):

  ```
  Some(2) zip Some('b') // Some((2, 'b'))
  Some(2) zip None      // None
  None zip Some('b')    // None
  None zip None         // None
  ```
- Before `Scala 2.13`, [`Option#zip`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Option.html#zip[B](that:scala.collection.GenIterable[B]):Option[(A,B)]) was returning an `Iterable` and it was possible to combine it with `headOption`:

  ```
  Some(2) zip Some('b') headOption // Some((2, 'b'))
  Some(2) zip None headOption      // None
  ```

Comment: That's exactly what the question is asking for: getting something if and only if both parts are defined.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood then. Seemed to me the poster asked for `Tuple2<Option<K>, Option<V>> -> Option<Tuple2<K,V>>` and `zip` provides (more or less) `Option<T1> -> Option<T2> -> Option<Tuple2<T1, T2>>`.

Comment: Got confused by the usage of `opposite` in your original comment. Each part of the initial `Tuple2<Option<K>, Option<V>>` can be accessed in order to reach the input state of this answer (`tuple._1 zip tuple._2`). Decided not to include that bit as extracting parts of a tuple is fairly obvious and the interesting bit is the `zip` part.

Comment: "Fairly obvious"... at least not for me, at first :)

Answer (score 4):

```
scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> import Scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> (Tuple2.apply[Int, Int] _).lift[Option].tupled
res5: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) => Option[(Int, Int)] = <function1>

scala> res5((some(3), some(11)))
res6: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((3,11))

scala> res5((some(3), none))
res7: Option[(Int, Int)] = None
```

Comment: This is nice, but I think using the fact that tuples are bitraversable is a little nicer.

Comment: Fwiw, this looks ugly because Scala can't infer types in many cases. In Haskell, `res5 = uncurry $ liftA2 (,)`.