# How do I convert an option tuple to a tuple of options in Scala?

Tags: scala, tuples, scala-option

This question is the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408086/converting-a-tuple-of-options-to-an-option-of-tuple-with-scalaz-or-shapeless).

```
val x = Some((1, 2))
val (y: Option[Int], z: Option[Int]) = ???
```

Both pure Scala answers and Scalaz anwers are helpful.

Comment: I wonder if Shapeless (https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) provides a succinct answer for this?

Comment: You can get an iterator with tuple.productIterator. There is also a productArity and productElement(n: Int)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually think your answer is perfectly clear, but since you mention Scalaz, this operation is called `unzip`:

```
scala> import scalaz._, std.option._
import scalaz._
import std.option._

scala> val x: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1, 2))
x: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1,2))

scala> Unzip[Option].unzip(x)
res0: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(1),Some(2))
```

You should be able to write simply `x.unzip`, but unfortunately the standard library's horrible implicit conversion from `Option` to `Iterable` will kick in first and you'll end up with an `(Iterable[Int], Iterable[Int])`.

---

Looking back a year later: it's actually possible to do this with Scalaz's `UnzipPairOps`:

```
scala> import scalaz.std.option._, scalaz.syntax.unzip._
import scalaz.std.option._
import scalaz.syntax.unzip._

scala> val x: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1, 2))
x: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1,2))

scala> x.unfzip
res0: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(1),Some(2))
```

What were you thinking, 2014 me?

Answer (score 8):

As per Jim's answer, but with a syntax that some may find easier to read:

```
val x = Some(1 -> 2)
val (y, z) = x map {case (a,b) => Some(a) -> Some(b)} getOrElse (None -> None)
```

Answer (score 7):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, this exact behavior is provided in the standard library by [`Option#unzip`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/Option.html#unzip[A1,A2](implicitasPair:A%3C:%3C(A1,A2)):(Option[A1],Option[A2])):

```
// val x: Option[(Int, String)] = Some(1, "hello")
x.unzip
// (Some(1), Some("hello"))
val (y, z) = x.unzip
// y: Option[Int] = Some(1)
// z: Option[String] = Some("hello")

// val x: Option[(Int, String)] = None
x.unzip
// (None, None)
```

Also note the equivalent for 3-element tuples: [`Option#unzip3`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/Option.html#unzip3[A1,A2,A3](implicitasTriple:A%3C:%3C(A1,A2,A3)):(Option[A1],Option[A2],Option[A3])).

Comment: Using the standard library should always be the preferred solution, when possible, rather than using extension libraries such as cats

Answer (score 6):

The best I could come up with is the following, but it looks goofy to me:

```
val x = Some((1, 2))
val (y, z) = x map {x => (Some(x._1), Some(x._2)) } getOrElse (None, None)
```

Comment: I don't think it's goofy at all, it describes what you are trying to do, I might just replace `x map {x => ...` with `x map {case (fst, snd) => ...` to avoid calling `_1` and `_2`.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by Rob Norris on the cats gitter channel, you can do this with cats by calling `.separate`:

```
@ import cats.implicits._
import cats.implicits._

@ val x: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1, 2))
x: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1, 2))

@ x.separate
res6: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(1), Some(2))
```

The type annotation in the assignment to `x` is relevant; the implicit operates on `Option` not on `Some`:

```
@ val x = Some((1, 2))
x: Some[(Int, Int)] = Some((1, 2))

@ x.separate
cmd2.sc:1: value separate is not a member of Some[(Int, Int)]
val res2 = x.separate
```

`separate` is provided by `cats.MonadCombine`

Comment: You can use `cats.syntax.option._` to get rid of type annotations. `(1, 2).some` will be infered as `Option[(Int, Int)]`.