# Combine monads into tuples operator scalaz

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scalaz

So a very very common pattern in Scala is a for comprehension as follows:

```
for {
  i <- monadA
  j <- monadB
} yield (i, j)
```

Similarly for 3-tuples, ..., n-tuples.  This is becoming so common in my code I'd imagine that scalaz provide some awesome operator to do this for me, e.g. `monadA funnyOperator monadB funnyOperator monadC`.  I've looked around and can't seem to find anything.  So I've defined my own implicit class for 2-tuples and 3-tuples but would prefer to use scalaz.

### Bonus

In response the currently accepted answer, would love to see someone tell how to make this compile:

```
import scalaz.Scalaz._

// Like a 1 element list
case class MyMonad[+T](x: T) {
  def map[U](f: T => U): MyMonad[U] = MyMonad(f(x))
  def flatMap[U](f: T => MyMonad[U]): MyMonad[U] = f(x)
}

val myMonad: MyMonad[(Int, Int)] = (MyMonad(1) |@| MyMonad(2)).tupled
```

and not give:

```
error: value |@| is not a member of MyMonad[Int]
```

### Bonus Solution:

You need to "provide an applicative instance" e.g.

```
implicit def myMonadApplicative: Bind[MyMonad] = new Bind[MyMonad] {
  def bind[A, B](fa: MyMonad[A])(f: A => MyMonad[B]): MyMonad[B] = fa.flatMap(f)
  def map[A, B](fa: MyMonad[A])(f: A => B): MyMonad[B] = fa.map(f)
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a tuple of options to an option of tuple with Scalaz or Shapeless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408086/converting-a-tuple-of-options-to-an-option-of-tuple-with-scalaz-or-shapeless)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I'm specifically looking for a syntactic sugar associated with all Monads. The linked question asks how to basically do a for-comprehension with Options.

Comment: The answers still apply. Despite the question, there's nothing specific to `Option` there.

Comment: Well I did a `CMD + F` for `|@|` and it wasn't there, nor any other kind of operator which is what I asked for.

Comment: The fact that another answer exists, doesn't mean the problem is not the same

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a syntactic sugar associated with all Monads. I'm specifically looking for an *operator*. The linked question just asks *how*, **I'm specifically looking for "an awesome operator"**. @GabrielePetronella The other question does not ask for this.  Therefore the questions are different. Now please remove your close vote :)

Comment: The other question is specific, but the problem is very much general, and all the answers address the problem generically for any `Applicative` (nothing specific to `Option` in any of them). What you care about are the answers, ultimately, so read them.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I'm specifically looking for a syntactic sugar associated with all Monads. I'm specifically looking for an operator.  Neither the question nor the answers provide such an operator.  I feel like we are going round in circles, how many times do I have to say *I'm looking for an operator* before you acknowledge I'm looking for an operator????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that each `Monad` is an `Applicative` you can also use

```
(monadA |@| monadB).tupled
```

E.g.

```
scala> val b: List[(Int, Int)] = (List(1, 2, 3) |@| List(4, 6)).tupled
b: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,4), (1,6), (2,4), (2,6), (3,4), (3,6))
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited to use `tupled` as it's a bit neater and won't change the syntax if the number of monads changes.  It doesn't seem to quite work with *all types* that have a `flatMap` & `map` though.  I tried it with a custom Monad and I got a compiler error.  Is there any implicit hocus pocus I need to make it work??? (updated question)

Comment: @samthebest |@| is the applicative builder operator. You will need to provide an `Applicative` instance for your custom class, in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sequence`; I can never remember whether you need shapeless-scalaz for this or not:

```
(monadA, monadB).sequence
(monadA, monadB, monadC).sequence
```

Comment: `(Option(12), Option(1)).sequence` returns `Some((Some(12),14))`, which does not seem correct. `bisequence` should work as intended, but it requires explicit types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408086/converting-a-tuple-of-options-to-an-option-of-tuple-with-scalaz-or-shapeless